# How can I tame a Horse in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to tame a wild horse or a donkey in Minecraft but I don't really know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be a duplicate, but i will answer it for you.

The best way(s) to tame a horse/donkey are:

1. (opt.) feed the horse golden apples to increase the chances of it being tamed.
2. Ride the horse. [Right-Click it.](it may buck you, so be prepared to try again. Repeat until you see hearts.)

How to ride your horse:

1. Right-click the horse with a saddle in your hand.
2. Place the saddle in the saddle slot.
3. Mount the horse, and ride it with normal Minecraft controls.

Answer (score 0):

To tame the horse, you must right click with an empty hand. Once tamed, ride it, press "e", and stick the saddle in